# Deserialize 2.6k lines XML in Dotnet 5

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-5

Is there a limit on how large xml strings can be to deserializein dotnet core (.net 5)?

Things were working OK for. but when I started getting 2500+lines of xml string, i get
'value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte'.

Troubleshooting:

- tested older versions of the same xml data (was had 2000+ lines, but less than the new one). so it's data related.
- tested with Visual Studio's `Paste as XML` to generate classes from xml. New and Old classes are exactly the same. So structure/schema is
  unchanged.
- tested the new xml in a few xml validation tools, all report that it has no errors. so it is not a data error.

from the above it seems i hit some limit.

Things I tried:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Text;

var stringReader = new StringReader(xmlStr);
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
var obj1 = serializer.Deserialize(stringReader) as MyClass;



var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlStr);
MemoryStream memStream = new(bytes);
var obj2 = serializers.Deserialize(memStream) as MyClass;
```

I tried targeting different `net5.0-windows7.0`, `net5.0-windows10.0.20348.0`, `net5.0-10.0.19041.0`

Any ideas of what could it be?
(sorry if my question is primitive, I am learning).

Comment: _value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte_ - this is a **data** problem, somewhere you have a value less than 0 or greater than 255 that you’re trying to assign to a `byte`

Comment: @stuartd, I have attributes like  ` <user id="867"/>`   
is that what you refer to?

Comment: Are you trying to store that value as a `byte`?

Comment: hmm. I just looked at what visual studio pasted.. 
 some fields are set to ushort, others to byte.. 


        /// <remarks />
        [XmlAttribute]
        public ushort id
        {
            get => idField;
            set => idField = value;
        }

`
/// <remarks />
        [XmlAttribute]
        public byte id
        {
            get => idField;
            set => idField = value;
        }`

Comment: OK i got it. if i changed all Byte to ushort, things work. Thanks for the clue !stuartd!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I used `Past XML as Class` clipboard command in Visual studio. It seems to have assigned `byte` to some integer values coming from the `xml string`, and some assigned `ushort`.
I did a replace all `byte` with `ushort` in the Visual Studio generated class, then things worked!